# Need REGEX for numbers to: REQUIRE 2 decimals, even if zeros, allow for negative sign

Tags: regex, decimal

I need a REGEX for a Google form that:

1. REQUIRES 2 decimals, even if zeros
2. ALLOWS for optional negative sign

It would allow:

```
-123.00
123.00
123.10
.20
```

It would NOT allow:

```
-123
-123.1
123.1
.2
```

Nothing exists that I could find that would require 2 decimals and allow for negative signs

Comment: Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/z0aRHq/1)

Comment: "Nothing exists that I could find that would require 2 decimals and allow for negative signs". Give us something to start with. Give us something that is close to what you want, and explain what's missing. Don't ask us to start from zero.

Answer (score -1):

hmm maybe something like this:

```
^-?\d+(\.(\d{2}))$
```

code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-heisenberg-637wfh?file=/src/index.js